# How do I pull all inactive conversations from twilio?

Tags: twilio

I know that I can get conversations with

```
await client.conversations.conversations.list({limit: 20)
```

but how do I only pull those conversations that are in-active?

I've tried

```
await client.conversations.conversations.list({
state: 'inactive'
limit: 20
)}
```

but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for fetching multiple conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-resource#read-multiple-conversation-resources) does not list any filters that you can use with the API, so it's not possible to filter conversations in the request.

Instead, you will need to fetch all the conversations and filter the inactive ones in your own code.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I can see this getting out of hand quickly though. Imagine having to pull thousands of conversations at once (or more) and sorting them to find out which one has any unread messages. I'm sure there's a better way?

Comment: If you want to keep track of new messages on conversations, you can [subscribe to conversations webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/conversations-webhooks) and store the state in your application. That will be easier than pulling all the conversations from the API.

Comment: I'm already pulling all the conversations using
await conversationsClient.getSubscribedConversations({limit: 200});

but this returns ALL conversations whether it's active or not. I would have liked to only subscribe to those that are active for instance but there's no way to do that.

Comment: [according to Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/conversations-limits#maximum-channelsconversations-per-identity), there's a limit of 1000 of active or inactive conversations per identity. So, not possible to pull thousands of conversation, just up to 1000